# Cordova NetworkState don't change after status update

Tags: networking, cordova

I've got the code below. If I start the function with wifi off (on my tab), i got an alert. So far so good. But if i turn on wifi then, i still got the alert, that i don't have connection.

Any ideas?

```
    //Kontrolle, ob benötigtes Netzwerk vorhanden ist
    function checkNetwork()
    {
        network()

        if (networkState != 'none')
        {
            networkState = '';
            writeDataToFile();
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Bitte die Internetverbindung checken');
            networkState = '';
            checkNetwork()
        }
    }

    //Welches Netzwerk ist gerade vorhanden
    function network()
    {
        networkState = navigator.connection.type;

        states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

        alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
    }
```

Comment: no idea? :( i tried some other things from this forum, but nothing really solved the problem.

Comment: it's strange, if i start "network()" directly, it identifies a change in the network state, if i do it like the code above, the problem written in the first post occurs